# Play for Scala: traverse all active sessions

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

To mark a user that has logged into my Play web application I store a flag in the session, like so:

```
Ok("Success").withSession("LoggedIn"-> "Yes")
```

Now, I need to know the number of users that are currently logged in and their names, is this possible without using a cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `withSession` sets a cookie in the client's browser with the data you provide, but does not store that data server side. There is no possible way to determine how many active cookies you've handed out, unless you add server side code to track them.

There are many other flaws with storing this data in a plain session like this, though. For example, the client can tamper with the cookie make it appear as if they're logged in. It would be better to use an existing and vetted authentication library such as Play2-auth, SecureSocial, etc, rather than rolling your own.

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at the libraries and they don't seem to have commercial support (I need this for my project). Isn't there a simple technique to mark the session, if `withSession` is not recommended?

Comment: So your product manager rejects a common, maintained and "vetted" community reviewed library because it has no commercial support, while he accepts the risks of a possibly buggy inhouse solution, designed without broad community review, driven  by StackOverflow Q&As?    As a security concept???

Comment: @ps0604 Proper authentication is anything but simple.